# Error JSF 2.1.at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig$LibraryHandler.endElement

Tags: spring, jsf, richfaces, spring-webflow

I have a error when run my myfaces(JSF 2.1), richfaces 4, 2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, in Jboss 7.0.2 "Arc":

```
11:50:33,556 SEVERE [org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Error Loading Library: vfs:/opt/jboss-as-7.0.2.Final/standalone/deployments/projvehimerc.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar/META-INF/jsf-html.taglib.xml: java.io.IOException: Error parsing [vfs:/opt/jboss-as-7.0.2.Final/standalone/deployments/projvehimerc.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar/META-INF/jsf-html.taglib.xml]: 
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:637) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.loadImplicit(TagLibraryConfig.java:668) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.Compiler.initialize(Compiler.java:97) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compileViewMetadata(Compiler.java:129) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory._createViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:355) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.access$100(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:53) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:120) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:117) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.FaceletCacheImpl.getViewMetadataFacelet(FaceletCacheImpl.java:112) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.FaceletCacheImpl.getViewMetadataFacelet(FaceletCacheImpl.java:50) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:430) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:420) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage._getViewMetadataFacelet(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2115) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.access$000(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:129) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage$FaceletViewMetadata.createMetadataView(FaceletViewDeclarationLanguage.java:2225) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:162) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:171) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189) [myfaces-api-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:343) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:90) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:188) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149) [spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:139) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.NamingValve.invoke(NamingValve.java:57) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:154) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:667) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:952) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_25]
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Error Handling [vfs:/opt/jboss-as-7.0.2.Final/standalone/deployments/projvehimerc.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets-1.1.15.B1.jar/META-INF/jsf-html.taglib.xml@25,74] <library-class>
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig$LibraryHandler.endElement(TagLibraryConfig.java:454) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:596)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLNSDTDValidator.endNamespaceScope(XMLNSDTDValidator.java:221)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:2049)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:923)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:673)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1645)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:324)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:845)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:768)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:108)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1196)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:555)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:289)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:198) [:1.6.0_25]
        at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:632) [myfaces-impl-2.1.1.jar:]
        ... 61 more

    11:50:33,802 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.util.ExternalSpecifications] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) MyFaces Unified EL support enabled
    11:50:33,974 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/projvehimerc]] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) No state saving method defined, assuming default server state saving
    11:50:34,859 INFO  [org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.TomcatAnnotationLifecycleProvider] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) Creating instance of org.richfaces.skin.SkinBean
```

This is my web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

<!-- Log4j configurated in spring!!!, 
before any code directly calling log4j (calling through commons logging doesn't count)? Jing Xue -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j-webapp.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jRefreshInterval</param-name>
        <param-value>1000</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
        <param-value>myWebapp-instance-root</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


<display-name>richfaces-application</display-name>
<!-- Listener para crear el Spring Container compartido por todos los 
Servlets y Filters (WebApplication Context)-->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath*:META-INF/spring/spring-master.xml
        WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
<!-- For JSF -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
<!-- Jboss not use it bundle integrated JSF -->
    <context-param>
    <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

<!-- Facelets, tell JSF to use Facelets -->
    <context-param>
    <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.VIEW_HANDLERS</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</param-value>
    </context-param>

<!-- Spring JavaServiceFaces framework ApacheMyfaces --> 
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

<!-- Spring Security, for all -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

<!-- RichFaces Framework -->
    <!--  RichFaces 4, no more Filter!!!
    <filter>
    <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>transportes</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    -->
    <context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
    <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- For control of skins -->
    <context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING_CLASSES</param-name>
    <param-value>enable</param-value>
    </context-param>

<!-- Servlets for JSF-->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<!-- Servlet for Dispatcher of flows -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>transportes</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/transportes-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup> 
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>transportes</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/flows/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Servlet register for SpringFaces, SpringJavaScript -->
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<!-- Page That control SpringWeb -->
    <!--  
    <error-page>
       <error-code>404</error-code>
       <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    -->
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/flows/inscripcion/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Why is this error?
thnks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the cause (perhaps corrupt JAR?), but you definitely shouldn't have the old Facelets 1.x `jsf-facelets.jar` in a JSF 2.x project. The JSF 2.x libraries already bundles Facelets 2.x. So removing the offending JAR should at least fix this problem.

Comment: Thns I used myfaces 2.1.3, but in mayor of tutorial myfaces configured with com.sun.facelets/jsf-facelets/1.1.15.B1, I commented this and the error disappear, thnks.